# mac yosmite, how to edit a file in the var/root folder

Tags: macos, mac

I'm new to mac and I've this file named config.properties in var/root/.
How do I edit this file and save it. I've searching for how to do this for some time and I'm really tired, not finding a solution. Can someone be kind enough to help me?

Regards.

Comment: Seems to me this might [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So while your question could be answered by [using sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo), I don't have such file there and I wonder if you should have that file. So: what is that file for?

Comment: See also Apple's [OS X Server: How to edit configuration files](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202292).

Comment: @Arjan that file was created by another user who was using this mac before me. It's for development purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an admin user you can type the following command in the Terminal.app to open TextEdit.app with root permissions.

`sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit`

You can also press command-shift-. to display invisible files in the Open menu of TextEdit if needed.

Comment: I wanted to confirm that this still works, as I once heard that the "automatic versions of files" that Apple apps try to keep, might prevent using TextEdit from changing such config files. But I cannot even run TextEdit using `sudo` anymore on Yosemite... (Nothing happens when I run the above command, and `ps -ef` does not show TextEdit either; not important for me.)

Comment: i typed the command in terminal, It did not open any textedit. "[1] 625" terminal prints this in the  next line when I press enter after entering the  command. I'm on 10.10.2

Comment: Sorry, the & in the end of the command put the password prompt into another session. I have updated the command and removed the & at the end.

Comment: still nothing happens, I did already got this answer googling. had no luck

Comment: @HeisenBerg, *"I did already got this answer googling"*, too bad you didn't mention that in your question! :-(

Comment: @Arjan sorry, my bad

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. You can edit it using nano editor.

in terminal type

```
sudo nano /var/root/config.properties
```

this will open the file nano editor inside the terminal. You can now make changes as needed. To save press Ctlr + O and hit enter, or press ctrl + x and hit Y and then hit enter.(instructions to save are at the bottom).

If anyone find a way to edit it using textedit, please post your answer